# .nil? value query when attached to an array

Tags: ruby, if-statement, null

I am working through the codecademy exercises and I cannot figure out what .nil? means in the way that I am required to implement it. Here is my code :

```
movies = { GIS: 10.0, Phantasm: 1.5, Bourne: 4.0}
puts "Whats your movie brah?"
title = gets.chomp
puts "What's your rating brah?"
rating = gets.chomp
movies[title] = rating
puts "Your info was totally saved brah!"
case movies
when 'add'
  puts "What movie do you want to add?"
  title = gets.chomp
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    puts "What's the rating? (Type a number 0 to 4.)"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    puts "#{title} has been added with a rating of #{rating}."
  else
    puts "That movie already exists! Its rating is #{movies[title.to_sym]}."
  end
when "update"
puts "Updated!"
when "display"
puts "Movies!"
when "delete"
puts "Deleted!"
else puts "Error!"
end
```

I am working though creating methods for each command starting with the "add" command. The thing that is totally confusing me though, is the

```
.nil?
```

From what I understand, 
    nil = false

So, what I am thinking is that

```
.nil?
```

is asking if the attached statement is false. The crux of my confusion based on the line :

```
if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
```

Is that line asking :

"If the title I just entered is already represented as a symbol in the movies array, is this statement then, false?"

In which case, I imagine the if statement would evaluate to true if the title does not exist and false if it already exists. If the movie is indeed new, it would lastly, simply ask for the pertinent info as stated in the

```
else
```

statement. If someone could help clarify my misunderstanding I would be very grateful!

Comment: `nil` and `false` are slightly different. `nil` means *missing* or *no value*, `false` means *has a false value*. `nil` is falsey in a boolean context though.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that friend. Now, I have a clearer understanding of what I am working with! Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.nil?` is asking if the object you are sending the `nil?` message to is actually an instance of `nil`.

```
'a string'.nil? #=> false
nil.nil?        #=> true

x = 'a string'
x.nil?          #=> false

x = nil
x.nil?          #=> true
```

Your understanding of how the `if movies[title.to_sym].nil?` conditional works is basically correct. By default if a value is not in a hash, the hash will return `nil`.

```
movies = { GIS: 10.0, Phantasm: 1.5, Bourne: 4.0 }

# Ignoring the user input
title = 'Bourne'

movies[title.to_sym].nil?
#=> movies["Bourne".to_sym].nil?
#=> movies[:Bourne].nil?
#=> 4.0.nil?
#=> false

movies[:NoSuchMovie].nil?
#=> nil.nil?
#=> true
```

Comment: Couldn't have said it any better

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a huge help to me! It told me exactly what I needed to know and you explained it very concisely. I'd give you 10 votes if I could!

Comment: Does Ruby know not to add a title that already exists because two symbols cannot have the same name? I am curious how it determines when the hash has no value.